# FLANN in matlab returns different distance from my own calculation

Tags: matlab, knn, flann

I'm using FLANN in matlab and using SIFT feature descriptor as my data. There is a function:

```
[result, ndists] = flann_search(index, testset, ...);
```

Here the `index` is built with kd-tree. The "user manual" said `result` returns the nearest neighbors of the samples in `testset`, and `ndists` contains the corresponding distances between the test samples and the nearest neighbors. I used the euclidean distance and found that the distances in `ndists` are different from that of computed by the orignal data. And even more strange, all the numbers in `ndists` are integers, which is often not possible for euclidean distance. Can you help me to explain this?

Comment: if the numbers in `ndists` are all integers - might it be the case that this output is actually the indices of the nearest neighbors found? what type are `result` numbers? are they double? are they integers? is it possible there is another output you omitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FLANN by default returns *squared* euclidean distance (x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + ... + x<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup>). You can change the used metric with  `flann_set_distance_type(type, order)` (see [manual](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/uploads/FLANN/flann_manual-1.8.4.pdf)).

An [example](https://gist.github.com/smidm/4099993e46e2802bb3bd78f5ffb1f33d):

```
from pyflann import *
import numpy as np

dataset = np.array(
    [[1., 1, 1, 2, 3],
     [10, 10, 10, 3, 2],
     [100, 100, 2, 30, 1]
     ])
testset = np.array(
    [[1., 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [90, 90, 10, 10, 1]
     ])

result, dists = FLANN().nn(
    dataset, testset, 1, algorithm="kmeans", branching=32, iterations=7, checks=16)
```

Output:

```
>>> result
array([0, 2], dtype=int32)
>>> dists
array([  5., 664.])
>>> ((testset[0] - dataset[0])**2).sum()
5.0
>>> ((testset[1] - dataset[2])**2).sum()
664.0
```

SIFT features are integers so the resulting distances are also integers in case of the *squared* euclidean distance.